# Java Runtime's exec() method is not executing correctly a shell script that invokes another shell script with redirect

Tags: java, bash, shell, weblogic

In my Spring-boot application, I am trying to trigger a shell script which in turns internally executes other shell script. I'm able to trigger my main script (say master.sh) using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), but thereon any scripts being called within master.sh do not run. In fact, nothing happens (I only get the output of the master.sh script).

Inside Java code:

```
     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Process proc = rt.exec(new String[] {"sh",
                    "/path_to_my_script/my_script.sh",
                    "--action="+action,
                    "--service="+service,
                    "--group="+groupsString,
                    "--username="+username,
                    "--desc='"+description+"'"});
            proc.waitFor();
            output = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line);
            if( line.contains("[") && line.contains("]") )
                    output.append(line.substring(line.indexOf("[") + 1, line.indexOf("]")));
            }
```

Inside my_script.sh I do different operations and then I finish executing the following lines:

```
printf "\n# -------------------------------------------- #\n"
printf "#           Executing my_script.sh script        #\n"
printf "# -------------------------------------------- #\n"

/path_to_other_script/wlst.sh <<+ > ${PWD}/output.txt
connect('username','password','10.0.0.0')
execfile('${PWD}/${pyScript}')
+

cat ${PWD}/output.txt

#rm -fr ${PWD}/${pyScript}
exit 0
```

Java can grab the first 3 lines (those with the printf) but the next execution /path_to_other_script/wlst.sh never executes and I don't understand why

I can call my script directly from command line and everything executes as expected and I'm able to double check the execution by doing a cat to output.txt

So, looks like exec is just understanding the execute of the "parent" process and not the child.

Any ideas?

I also tried to execute the script using ProcessBuilder with no luck:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "/u01/app/obieeWS/rest-webservices/obiee_scripts/obiee.sh",
                        "--action="+action,
                        "--service="+service,
                        "--group="+groupsString,
                        "--username="+username,
                        "--desc='"+description+"'");
pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p=pb.start();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you running your script from a command line using sh, or some other shell?

Comment: What happens in the exec'd process is beyond Java's reach.  My first thought is "what is the current directory?".   Add a print of $PWD.

Comment: Also, are any errors printed by the script(s) going someplace where you can see them?

Comment: @Shawn I'm running the script from a java app

Comment: @iggy I already verified the directories, I also tried to run it hardcoded to avoid problems on the path but is still not running

Comment: Yup @GordonDavisson , I have a redirect for the entire output but nothing is being captured. The weird thing is, Solaris can run the code without issues (exactly the same file structure, paths, etc but when we moved the code to Linux7 it stoped working in the same way

Comment: I have a hunch, the problem is related to this piece of code: /path_to_other_script/wlst.sh <<+ > ${PWD}/output.txt
connect('username','password','10.0.0.0')
execfile('${PWD}/${pyScript}')
+

Comment: What shell runs in response to the 'sh' command?

Comment: probably you have different environment variables at Solaris and Linux. I suggest you to add line ```env``` to see whether PATH variable contains all paths required for execution of ```wlst.sh```; and hardcode PATH variable in the ```master.sh``` to ensure PATH var is ok.